# Outlook calendar only shows busy with Full Access Permission

Tags: microsoft-outlook, permissions, calendar

Shared meeting room calendar is showing all the events as free/busy instead of the full details. It was showing the full details but after I deleted and re-add the same calendar, that's when I start to have problem.

I've done the followings but didn't seem to work.

- Allow full details as calendar's permissions.
- Unchecked Use Cached Exchange Mode
- Clear AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\RoamCache

Anyone has any ideal?

Comment: Are the events on the calendar marked private perhaps?

Comment: Don't think so, I delete the shared calendar that showed full details. Now when i add back the same calendar, it shows only as free/busy

Comment: Have you verified whether you can still see full details of the shared calendar in OWA?

Comment: Restarting the server helps.